# How to use position: absolute and have an automatic height

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

First off, let me note that I have not found an answer on any of the recommended questions, so this may be a duplicate in some sense, but my issue has not been resolved otherwise.

The issue is that I have a position: relative container which contains 5 images each with position absolute. I do this because I need the page to be mobile responsive. These two elements are container within a row (from a grid).

The row from the grid should have height: auto; and should resize according to the size of the container, since it's element is position relative not absolute, but it doesn't and my images end up overlapping the footer on my website.

I didn't include the jQuery below, but I'll tell you it doesn't manipulate the height or width or anything. It only changes the opacity of the images.

This is the CSS associated with the elements

```
.B9Resize { /*This is the row*/
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid #2f3030;
    min-height: 620px;
}

.slideshow-container {/*This is the container element*/
    width: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.slideshow-container img {/*These are the actual image properties*/
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.transparent-image {/*These are additional properties*/
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="row"> <!-- THIS IS THE ROW -->
        <div class="col-12 col-m-12 B9Resize"> 

            <div class="slideshow-container-marginFix">
                <div class="slideshow-container">
                    <img src="../images/slideshow1.jpg" alt="Bonsecours Market" id="image1" class="transparent-image">
                    <img src="../images/slideshow2.jpg" alt="Shoes Hanging on a Cherry Blossom Tree" id="image2" class="transparent-image">
                    <img src="../images/slideshow3.jpg" alt="Cat Sitting on Couch" id="image3" class="transparent-image">
                    <img src="../images/slideshow4.jpg" alt="Gift Bag with Pink Wrapping Paper" id="image4" class="transparent-image">
                    <img src="../images/slideshow5.jpg" alt="Pink Flower" id="image5" class="transparent-image">
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the exact result you want? A responsive sideshow?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine except the height of the row from the grid

Answer (score 0):

You should apply auto height to B9Resize instead of setting a min-height. if this doesn't work you may need to check .slideshow-container-marginFix and how js manipulate the style.

```css
.B9Resize { /*This is the row*/
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px solid #2f3030;
    height: auto;
}
.slideshow-container {/*This is the container element*/
    width: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.slideshow-container div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.slideshow-container img {/*These are the actual image properties*/
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: auto;
}

.transparent-image {/*These are additional properties*/
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> <!-- THIS IS THE ROW -->
  <div class="col-12 col-m-12 B9Resize">
    <div class="slideshow-container-marginFix">
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911220-e15b29be8c8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" alt="Bonsecours Market" id="image1" class="transparent-image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911220-e15b29be8c8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" alt="Shoes Hanging on a Cherry Blossom Tree" id="image2" class="transparent-image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911220-e15b29be8c8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" alt="Cat Sitting on Couch" id="image3" class="transparent-image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911220-e15b29be8c8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" alt="Gift Bag with Pink Wrapping Paper" id="image4" class="transparent-image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911220-e15b29be8c8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" alt="Pink Flower" id="image5" class="transparent-image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would think, but the height of the row, and the height of the container are 0 because the images are absolutely positioned, meaning they don't have an impact on their parent elements.

Comment: I would suggest you not to use absolute position and hide overflowed content in .slideshow-container. Then use js to update position / animate images.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Add a div to wrap all images and force it to single row.

Comment: how does this answer the OP `How to use position: absolute and have an automatic height`? you have not used `position: absolute `

Answer (score 0):

If you know using `postion:absolute`, then you should also be knowing that its not possible to calculate parent height with absolute positioned children, using css.

> Absolutely positioned elements are completely removed from the
>   document flow, so their dimensions cannot alter the dimensions
>   of their parents.

Now, if you really want to achieve this, you can use JavaScript/jQuery to find the height of the `img` and then set it for `.slideshow-container` div.